# phpThumb resize to fixed height but dynamic width?

Tags: php, gd, phpthumb

I'm using phpThumb (mainly because of the excellent reflection addon) and need to resize an image to a specific height, and the width be taken care of automatically (dynamic).

Looking at the documentation, it seems to require both width and height parameters:
https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki/Basic-Usage

Is there any way around this or do I have to resort to the usual GD image method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with `the usual GD image method` but if you use [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) (yes, GD...) to get the image dimensions, you can easily calculate the new width and use phpThumb like you do now.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. Thats what I've had to do. Shame that functionality isn't built in though.

Comment: @iltdev Yes, that would seem like a thing that should be there.